# Solve $\lim\limits_{x\to1}x^{1/(1-x)}$ with L'Hospital's rule, not standard limit

Tags: limits

I need to solve

$$ \lim_{x\to 1}\,x^{\dfrac{1}{1-x}}$$

using L'Hospital's rule and $\ln$, without standard limit.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Ha! What is 'wonderful limit'?

Comment: Sorry, I might miss spell. For this case it's (1+1/x)^(x/1)=e

Comment: I don't know. Maybe some people call it that way.

Comment: This is almost the definition of $e$. If you cannot use the definition of $e$, how would you solve this?

Comment: Using ln and L'Hopital's rule

Comment: You could do $x^{1/(1-x)}=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}\right)$. Then compute the limit of $\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}$ by L'Hospital from the limit of $-\frac{1}{x}$, which is $-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Let consider

$$A^B=e^{B\ln A} \implies x^{\dfrac{1}{1-x}}=e^{\dfrac{\ln x}{1-x}}$$

and by continuity

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\,x^{\dfrac{1}{1-x}}=e^{\left(\lim_{x\to 1}\dfrac{\ln x}{1-x}\right)}$$

Comment: But it is still unsolved. You get $$e^{ln(1)/(1-1}$$

Comment: Why don't apply l'Hospital to ${\dfrac{\ln x}{1-x}}$?

Comment: Oh, tank you. You get $$(1/x)*(1/-1)$$

Answer (score 2):

If $$ L=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)^{g(x)} \rightarrow 1^{\infty}$$, then
$$L=\exp~[\lim_{x \rightarrow a} [g(x)~(f(x)-1)].$$
So, here $$=\exp\left[\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \left(\frac{1}{1-x}~(x-1)\right)\right]=e^{-1}.$$